# Printing a string in C with pointer arithmetic including arrays, integers and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, char, pointer-arithmetic

There are three structures; arrays `a` and `b` and pointer `c`:

```
c --------------------------.
                            |
                            V
       ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
a --> | a | \0| \0| \0| \0| b | i | g | \0| \0| r | i | d | e | \0|
       ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´
       ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
b --> | F | l | y | i | n | g | \0|
       ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´ ´´´
```

This is the code:

```
int main(){
   char a[3][5]={"a", "big", "ride"};
   char b[]="Flying";
   char *c=*(a+1);

   puts(b+(c-*a)-2);

   return 0;
}
```

Now what I can't understand is the expression `b+(c-*a)-2`. Can someone be kind and break it down?

Comment: `c - *a` is a difference between pointers. It gets converted (in a implementation defined manner) to int in your expression. `b + int - 2` is basic pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @pmg What I do not understand is how come this compiles: `char *c=*(a+1);` I thought the right-hand-side expression is of type `char*`, therefore dereferencing it would yield a `char`, not a `char*`.

Comment: `a` by itself, in that expression, decays to a pointer to its first element (to `&a[0]`). `(&a[0]) + 1` is the same as `&(a[1])`. Applying the indirection operator gives `a[1]`: a pointer to char. That pointer is then assigned to `c`, another pointer to char.

Answer (score 8):

- `b+(c-*a)-2` is the same as `&b[(c-*a)-2]`. In other words, if `(c-*a)-2` is an offset into string `b`, `puts(b+(c-*a)-2)` would print the string `b` starting from the position at the `(c-*a)-2` offset.
- `c` is assigned `*(a+1)`, or *(&(a[1])), or simply `a[1]`, which points to `"big"`
- Count the squares on your diagram to find the value of `c-*a` (it is 5)
- `b[5-2]` is `"ing"`

Disclaimer: if anyone tried to check in such code at my company, he would no longer be working for us.

Comment: +1 for "I'll explain it, but please don't write like this" :)

Comment: Sorry to tag on here, but why does 'b+' compile to '&b[]'

Comment: @quicksort Address of array's initial element `&b[0]` is the same as the value of the pointer `b`, which is in turn the same as `b+0`. According to the rules of pointer arithmetics, adding `n` to `b` is the same as taking the address of a value at the offset of `n` times the size of b's element from the base `b`, which is `b[n]`.